# i have many sentences in a hmd.txt file and i want to split each sentences by " " in one paragraph from whole text file. e.g

Tags: python

"I couldn't decide between these three cameras (and their variants, the Sony HX30 and the Panasonic ZX20) because many of the reviews of each made the cameras sound very similar.  So, I went out and bought (from merchants who accepted returns) one of each of these three cameras.  And then I took photos and videos in various conditions.  I am not a professional photographer, and I didn't do Imatest or any other specific tests on the images (you can read C/net for that), but this is an experience of a regular person who was taking pictures and videos with these three cameras side by side, which is a comparison that you do not often see."

"The bottom line is that these three cameras are very similar with a few minor differences.But those differences set them apart and may make you decide that you like one more than the other."

"Generally speaking, NONE of these cameras is a DSLR replacement.  Whomever writes that the pictures are as good as a DSLR is not speaking accurately.  Also, none of the cameras is a replacement for a high end camcorder."

the output I need is

1. "I couldn't decide between these three cameras (and their variants, the Sony HX30 and the Panasonic ZX20) because many of the reviews of each made the cameras sound very similar."

   2. "So, I went out and bought (from merchants who accepted returns) one of each of these three cameras."
2. "And then I took photos and videos in various conditions."  .......so on

Comment: What's wrong with `.split(". ")`?

Comment: thanks i have found the code well can you help me for finding out the count for POS tags for paragraphs in " " as above

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it, you ask about sentences and then post code that splits by words? Am I missunderstanding something, I believe you were looking for something like:

text = """ [copy-paste-example-text] """

```
for possible_paragraph in text.split("\n"):
    if len(possible_paragraph) != 0:
        paragraphs.append(possible_paragraph)
        sentences.append([])
        for sentence in paragraphs[-1].split(". "):
            if len(sentence) != 0:
                sentences[-1].append(sentence)
```

which gives the final results as

```
>>> sentences[0]
[prints out first paragraph from "I couldn't decide..." to "which is a comparison you don't often see]
>>> sentences[1]
[prints out the 2nd paragraph "The bottom line is..."]
```

and you get the sentence separation i.e. first sentence of first paragraph:

```
>>> sentences[0][0]
'"I couldn\'t decide between these three cameras (and their variants, the Sony HX30 and the Panasonic ZX20) because many of the reviews of each made the cameras sound very similar'
```

second sentence first paragraph

```
>>> sentences[0][1]
'So, I went out and bought (from merchants who accepted returns) one of each of these three cameras'
```

first sentence second paragraph....

```
>>> sentences[1][0]
'"The bottom line is that these three cameras are very similar with a few minor differences.But those differences set them apart and may make you decide that you like one more than the other."'
```

etc...

"And then I took..." is not the second paragraph because there's no enter between it and previous sentence either because of bad formatting on your part (not accounting SO rendering) or my misunderstanding of what you need/what paragraph is.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>>import re
# reading a file and reading line in it 
>>>text = ''.join(open('file.txt').readlines())
# reading sentences by separating them 
>>>sentences = re.split(r' *[][]* *', text)
>>>print (sentences)
```

now this code is separating the sentences.